# Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager' (Spring 5.3.8)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring5

I am trying to migrate a Spring application from Spring 4.3.26 to Spring 5.3.8. So have setup my pom file. But when I deploy my war file, I get the below error:

```
20-Sep-2021 17:56:08.971 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'appServlet1'
20-Sep-2021 17:56:15.061 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [appServlet1] threw exception
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'mediaTypes' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1660)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'mediaTypes' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:134)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1555)
        ... 49 more
20-Sep-2021 17:56:15.061 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [appServlet1] in web application [/palgui] threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException details (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1:
    org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'mediaTypes' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1660)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:315)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeType.<init>(Lorg/springframework/util/MimeType;)V
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:511)
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:623)
        at org.springframework.http.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:605)
        at org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.lambda$setMediaTypes$0(ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.java:209)
        at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:879)
        at org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.setMediaTypes(ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean.java:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:354)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:470)
        ... 54 more
```

My pom file's Spring dependencies are:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And my XML Files is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
        configure as beans -->
    <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.appgui.common" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Resolve logical view names to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views 
        directory -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/velocity/" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Code an intercepter to prevent GUI usage when PAL isn't ready -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.appgui.common.AppStartupInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

Can you please tell me if I need to add or remove some other jars on this? I am a bit baffled at this. Any pointers is appreciated.